# Yii2 & React : actionLogin blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, reactjs, yii2

I am using Yii2 as server side and React on client side.

1. Server : Running on http://localhost:8081
2. Client : Running on http://localhost:3000

I set urlManager as config like this

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [
                        'v1/auth' => 'v1/auth' //controller
                    ],
                    'patterns' => [
                        'POST' => 'login', // action
                    ],
                    'pluralize' => false,
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [
                        'v1/note' => 'v1/note'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

I run the application on the Server side using `php yii serve localhost --docroot = "api" --port = 8081`

```
<?php


namespace app\api\modules\v1\controllers;

use app\models\User;
use yii\filters\Cors;
use yii\rest\Controller;;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function behaviors(){

        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => Cors::class,
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'], // restrict access to
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['X-Wsse'], 
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }

    protected function verbs()
    {
        return [
            'login' => ['POST'],
        ];
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        // Tangkap data login dari client (username & password)
        $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
        $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

        // validasi jika kosong
        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            $response = [
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'username & password tidak boleh kosong!',
            ];
        } else {

            //  alot of code here
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```

I tried running it on Insomnia, and it worked.

Then I tried it on React on the client side, the results didn't work properly.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Card, Col, Container, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./login.css";

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      rememberMe: "",
    };
  }

  handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      password: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleRememberMe = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      rememberMe: event.target.checked,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    };

    const url = "http://localhost:8081/v1/auth";

    axios
      .post(url, { user })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    // destructure
    const { username, password, rememberMe } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="login-page">
        <Container>
          <Row className="d-flex justify-content-md-center align-items-center vh-100">
            <Col sm={12} md={6}>
              <Card>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <Card.Header>Sign In</Card.Header>
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Form.Group controlId="loginform-username">
                      <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="loginform-password">
                      <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="loginform-rememberme">
                      <Form.Check
                        type="checkbox"
                        label="Remember Me"
                        value={rememberMe}
                        onChange={this.handleRememberMe}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Card.Body>
                  <Card.Footer>
                    <Button
                      variant="primary"
                      type="submit"
                      className="float-right"
                    >
                      Login
                    </Button>
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                  </Card.Footer>
                </Form>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The results failed as follows.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/v1/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Any help it so appreciated.
```

Comment: Does it work if you enable OPTION method for your action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It seems like you do not have a mapping for the `OPTIONS` method.

The request probably results in a `404` response from the server that does not include the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header and the browser refuses to process it. You need to configure the controller to send the correct response.

On the rules' configuration add

```php
'OPTIONS' => 'options'
```

```php
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => [
                'v1/auth' => 'v1/auth' //controller
            ],
            'patterns' => [
                'POST' => 'login', // action
                'OPTIONS' => 'options'
            ],
            'pluralize' => false,
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => [
                'v1/note' => 'v1/note'
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Update the controller with the next few lines, there are some comments in the code.

```php
<?php

namespace app\api\modules\v1\controllers;

use app\models\User;
use yii\filters\Cors;
use yii\rest\Controller;;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    // Add more verbs here if needed
    protected $_verbs = ['POST','OPTIONS'];

    public function behaviors(){

        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        // remove auth filter before cors if you are using it
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => Cors::class,
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'], // restrict access to
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => $this->_verbs,
                // Not sure if you are using authorization filter
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['content-type','authorization'], 
                // Try '*' first, once it works, make it more restrictive
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
            ],
        ];

        // re-add authentication filter if you are using it.
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::class,
        ];
        // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method) if using authentication filter.
        $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options', 'login'];

        return $behaviors;
    }

    // I do not think you need this method, 
    // this should already be mapped in the rules
    protected function verbs()
    {
        return [
            'login' => ['POST'],
        ];
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        // Tangkap data login dari client (username & password)
        $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
        $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

        // validasi jika kosong
        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            $response = [
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'username & password tidak boleh kosong!',
            ];
        } else {

            //  alot of code here
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Send the HTTP options available to this route
     */
    public function actionOptions()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS') {
            Yii::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(405);
        }
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->getHeaders()->set('Allow', implode(', ', $this->_verbs));
    }
}
```